# Setting time Zone in MS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

i am using php with mssql, on windows azure cloud storage ,
when i insert datetime with code then it insert

```
 '2013-05-30 11:31:47.000'
```

(which is correct time with indian time zone)

but when i use `getdate()` to insert in other column it inserts `'2013-05-30 06:01:46.507'`

1. any idea how can we set default time zone to indian delhi - with any database settings /azure ?

Comment: whenever if you call getdate() method it gets the system current time, insert time vary every time you insert data into column.

Comment: Just an fyi, if you have control over the table, using DateTimeOffset data type makes these issues mostly go away.

Answer (score 4):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx), `getdate()` returns the current database system timestamp:

> This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on
>   which the instance of SQL Server is running.

You can [change the timezone](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/wely/archive/2011/06/26/setting-timezone-in-windows-azure.aspx) with `tsutil.exe`:

```
tzutil /s "India Standard Time"
```

Comment: it changes time zone for whole windows system, then ms sql shares it.

Comment: SQL Server ought to support setting the timezone independently of the system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the command prompt
2. Run the command tzutil /s "your specific time zone"
3. Ex : tzutil /s "India Standard Time".

Then it will system time zone and sql server too...