# How can I change default timezone of SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, timezone, liquibase

I have a Spring application and my JVM is running on UTC. But there are third party libraries which use GETDATE() and save data in system timezone.

Like Liquibase inserts datetime value in DatabaseChangeLog table using GETDATE().

To solve that problem I reach to a conclusion that I need to change default timezone of SqlServer.

How can I do that?
OR is there some other way to tackle this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting time Zone in MS SQL Server Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830012/setting-time-zone-in-ms-sql-server-database)

Comment: Perhaps setting `timeZone` parameter to your jdbc connection properties will help. https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-time-zone-configuration-using-hibernate/

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/993fe4d6-6e77-44aa-9ed4-98e0d21e48bf/how-to-change-the-default-sql-time-zone-to-gmt-0300?forum=transactsql), it seams like you just have to change the system timezone.